# Wireless connection notifications not showing up ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, notification

I'm running ubuntu 18.04.      Wireless is working fine but I'm not notified when I'm connected or disconnected.       I've checked using dconf-editor the settings in org->gnome->nm-applet and everything is as it should be, i.e., the only button that's on is `show-applet`.    Can anybody advise please?